# Using SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY in CONVERT function

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to create a function that will receive any datatype, and return a default value for that datatype.
I can get the datatype using

```
SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@foo,'BaseType')
```

According to the documentation, this function returns a sysname datatype
(see: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178550.aspx)

But trying to use it in a convert function is yielding an error:

```
Select Convert(SQL_VARIANT_PROPERTY(@foo,'BaseType'),@bar)
```

Incorrect syntax near 'BaseType'.

Is there any way of implementing this?

Thanks!

Comment: This can't even be done with dynamic SQL (since a function can't execute dynamic SQL). Even if you *could* do this, since the function result would itself be dynamic, how would it help? What problem is this supposed to solve that the caller can't?

Comment: Incidentally, there *is* a way to write an expression that will yield a `NULL` of the same type as `@foo`, regardless of the type of `@foo`, *provided* `@foo` is of a comparable type (that is, not something like `NTEXT`): `NULLIF(@foo, @foo)`. You can combine this with `ISNULL` to turn that `NULL` into a default value other than `NULL`, but that would require you to actually know the type in most cases (otherwise you don't know an appropriate literal that converts). I can't immediately think of any use for this, though -- implicit conversion of `NULL` will do fine in most any case.

Comment: The problem I'm trying to solve is this: I want to replace null values with a default value that I'll set in the function. Something along the lines of defaultIfNull([country]) would return an empty string.

Comment: Yeah, I'm afraid you'll have to settle for `ISNULL` and repeating your desired defaults. There's not really a way to capture this conveniently in a  T-SQL function.